# How do I render react dynamic components in slides with swiper?

Tags: reactjs, api, jsx, swiper.js

I'm displaying data gotten from an API on the interface of my website using map method.

```
//mapping over search result data and passing it to search component as props
 const moveEl = searchData.map(movie =>(
      <Search id={movie.id}  name={movie.name} image={movie.poster_path} summary={movie.overview}/>
    )
---------
<div>
  {moveEl}
</div>
```

I want to render this data as slides but if I can't hardcode them into swiper, what should I do instead please?

```
      <Swiper watchSlidesProgress={true} slidesPerView={7} className="mySwiper">
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 7</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 8</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 9</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map method inside Swiper component.

```jsx
<Swiper watchSlidesProgress={true} slidesPerView={7} className="mySwiper">
  {searchData.map(movie => (
    <SwiperSlide key={movie.id}>
      <Search id={movie.id}  name={movie.name} image={movie.poster_path} summary={movie.overview}/>
    </SwiperSlide>
  )}
</Swiper>
```